# Scrape multiple urls from csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import csv

with open("safari history.csv") as f_urls, open("Titles.txt", "w", newline="") as f_output:

    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(['Title'])

    for url in f_urls:
        #url = url.strip()
        #t = lxml.html.parse(url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
        titles = soup.find_all('meta')
        print( [meta.attrs['content']for meta in titles if 'name' in meta.attrs and meta.attrs['name'] == 'description'])
        csv_output.writerow([titles])
```

However, the connection dies and I get an error. Is there code that would 'skip' a faulty scrape, or something of the sort?

My 'end goal' is to group keywords from my web history into categories:

> geographical location, gender, age, etc.

This is to see how accurately our web history represents us.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the entire content, Traceback of the error?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a specific error that keeps getting thrown, you could use a try/except block to handle a success and simply pass on error:

```
try:
    do_work(url)
except YourExceptionType:
    #Do nothing
    pass
```

Small example from the shell:

```
>>> float("not a float")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#51>", line 1, in <module>
    float("not a float")
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'not a float'
>>> s = "not a float"
>>> try:
    print(float(s))
except ValueError:
    print("Exception caught")


Exception caught
>>>
```